# event listener of javascript converting drop down list to input button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is JavaScript which creates a polygon or line depending on the radio button selected.

I want to convert my code as such that instead of radio button, I can execute function using simple input button. Do I have to write seperate event listeners for both buttons?

If so, how will I call them in HTML? Or will one event listener do just fine? How will the events be handled then?

```
    function onPageLoaded() 
    {
        canvas.addEventListener("click", onCanvasClick, false);
        setInterval(updateScreen, 100);
    }

    function onCanvasClick(e) 
    {
        var x = e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop;

        switch (byId('shapeType').value)
        {
            case 'poly': polyClick(x,y);
                         break;
            case 'line': lineClick(x,y);
                         break;
        }
    }
```

Instead of this

```
<select id='shapeType'>
    <option value="poly" selected>Polygon</option>
    <option value="line">Line</option>
</select>
```

I want to use this

```
<input type="button" value="Add polygon">
  <input type="button" value="Add line">
```

For full code u can see the solution of this thread
http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/693319/unable-to-draw-more-then-1-shape-on-html5-canvas#answer1

Comment: @mughees.. i don't see the radio button anywhere

Comment: sorry drop down list it is
the main problem was to convert the code from single id that drop down list and radio button use with different id that button use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way.. Add a common class to the buttons and then write up the code for the same.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Add polygon" class="draw" data-type="poly">
<input type="button" value="Add line" class="draw" data-type="line">
```

**JS**

```
function onPageLoaded() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('draw');
    for(var i=0;i < buttons.length; i++) {
         buttons[i].addEventListener("click", onButtonClick, false);
    }
    setInterval(updateScreen, 100);
}

function onCanvasClick(e) {
    var x = e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop;

    switch (this.getAttribute("data-type")) {
        case 'poly': polyClick(x,y);
                     break;
        case 'line': lineClick(x,y);
                     break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I am adding the whole code. You have to add a variable graphtype. In onButtonClick, you set it. Then you draw based on graphtype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>
var END_CLICK_RADIUS = 5;
//the max number of points of your poygon
var MAX_POINTS = 8;

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var isStarted = false;

var points = null;
var polygons = null;
var lines = null;

var canvas = null;
var ctx = null;
var graphtype="polygon";


window.addEventListener('load', onPageLoaded, false);
function onPageLoaded() {

}

function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

//object representing a point
function Point(x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// object representing a polygon
function Polygon(points, color)
{
    this.points = points;
    this.color = color;
}

// object representing a single line segment
function LineSegment(point1, point2, color)
{
    this.p1 = point1;
    this.p2 = point2;
    this.color = color;
}

function onPageLoaded() 
{
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('draw');
    for(var i=0;i < buttons.length; i++) {
         buttons[i].addEventListener("click", onButtonClick, false);
    }

              canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    setColor( byId('color').value );

    canvas.addEventListener("click", onCanvasClick, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onCanvasMouseMove, false);

    polygons = new Array();
    lines = new Array();

    //refresh time
    setInterval(updateScreen, 100);
}
function onButtonClick(e){
      switch (this.getAttribute("data-type")) {
        case 'poly': graphtype="polygon";
                     break;
        case 'line': graphtype="line";
                     break;
       }

}

function onCanvasMouseMove(e)
{
    mouseX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
}

function addPolygon()
{
    polygons[polygons.length] = new Polygon(points, byId('color').value);
    alert(polygons.length + " polygons completed");
}

function addLine()
{
    lines[lines.length] = new LineSegment(points[0], points[1], byId('color').value);
}

function onCanvasClick(e) 
{
    var x = e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop;

    switch ( graphtype) 
    {
        case 'polygon': polyClick(x,y);
                     break;
        case 'line': lineClick(x,y);
                     break;
    }
}


function lineClick(x,y)
{
    if (isStarted)
    {
        points[points.length] = new Point(x,y);
        addLine();
        reset();
        isStarted = false;
    //  points = new Array();
    }
    else
    {
        isStarted = true;
        points = new Array();
        points[points.length] = new Point(x,y);
    }
}

function polyClick(x, y)
{
    if(isStarted) 
    {
        //drawing the next line, and closing the polygon if needed
        if(Math.abs(x - points[0].x) < END_CLICK_RADIUS && Math.abs(y - points[0].y) < END_CLICK_RADIUS) 
        {
            isStarted = false;
            addPolygon();
            reset();
        } 
        else 
        {
            points[points.length] = new Point(x, y);
            if(points.length >= MAX_POINTS) 
            {
                addPolygon();
                reset();
            }
        }
    } 

    else if(points == null) 
    {
        //opening the polygon
        points = new Array();
        points[0] = new Point(x, y);
        isStarted = true;
    }
}


//changes the color of the draw
function setColor(color)
{
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
}

//resets the application
function reset() 
{
    isStarted = false;
    points = null;
}

// called whenever the screen needs updating
function updateScreen()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    switch ( graphtype)
    {
        case 'polygon': 
            drawIncompletePolygon();
            break;
        case 'line':    
            drawIncompleteLine();
            break;
    }


    var i, n;
    n = polygons.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        drawPolygon(polygons[i]);

    n = lines.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        drawLineSegment(lines[i]);

}

// draws an arbitrary polygon. Takes a Polygon object as the input
function drawPolygon(polyToDraw)
{
    setColor(polyToDraw.color);
    var i, n = polyToDraw.points.length;
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.moveTo(polyToDraw.points[0].x, polyToDraw.points[0].y);
    for (i=1; i<n; i++)
        ctx.lineTo(polyToDraw.points[i].x, polyToDraw.points[i].y);

    ctx.lineTo(polyToDraw.points[0].x, polyToDraw.points[0].y);

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawLineSegment(lineSegToDraw)
{
    setColor(lineSegToDraw.color);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(lineSegToDraw.p1.x, lineSegToDraw.p1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(lineSegToDraw.p2.x, lineSegToDraw.p2.y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawIncompleteLine()
{
    if (isStarted)
    {
        setColor(byId('color').value);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
        ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}


function onCanvasClick(e) {
    var x = e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop;

    switch ( graphtype){
        case 'polygon': polyClick(x,y);
                     break;
        case 'line': lineClick(x,y);
                     break;
    }
}

//draws the current **in-progress** shape
function drawIncompletePolygon() 
{
    setColor(byId('color').value);

    ctx.beginPath();

    if(points != null && points.length > 0) 
    {
        ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);

        for(i = 1 ; i < points.length ; i++) 
        {
            ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
        }

        if(isStarted) 
        {
            ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        } 
        else 
        {
            ctx.lineTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
        }
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
</script>

<style>
body
{
    margin: 0;      
}

#board
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;   
}

#myCanvas
{
    border: 3px dotted #000;        
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="board">
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
<br />
Couleur : <select id="color" onchange="setColor(this.value);">
    <option value="red" selected="selected">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="black">black</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Add polygon" class="draw" data-type="poly">
<input type="button" value="Add line" class="draw" data-type="line">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```